# C++ Random & Array

Tags: c++, random

I try to use the random function for different things.
For now it works but I get one problem is I want to generate randomly the F in my code but they need to become array after. Also I need to use it and if I need to do it 1 by 1 I think my code will be  too long and messy.
Do you know how I can do this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    srand(time(0));
    //random numbers 1 to 10 for Time:
    int t = rand() % 10 + 1 ;
    cout << "There is "<< t << " Time;
    int* F1 = new int [t];
    int* F2 = new int [t];
    int* F3 = new int [t];
    int* F4 = new int [t];
    int* F5 = new int [t];
    cout << "Time per F: 0 Not available, 1 available;
    //For F1
    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++){
        //random numbers 0 or 1:
        F1[i] = rand() % 2 ;
    }
    cout << "The Time for F1 is ";
    for(int a = 0; a < t; a++){
        cout << " "<< F1[a] <<" ";
    } 
    //For F2
    for(int j = 0; j < t; j++){
        //random numbers 0 or 1:
        F2[j] = rand() % 2 ;
    }
    cout << "The Time slot for F2 is ";
    for(int b = 0; b < t; b++){
        cout << " "<< F2[b] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Edit: With the solution you give me helps to find the solution
I do int F[em][t];

Comment: `cout << "Time per F: 0 Not available, 1 available;` this line is syntactically wrong. Edit: There are more than 1 syntax errors in this code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't ask new questions as an edit. If an answer helped you to solve the problem as stated, [please mark it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq/#howtoask) and ask a new (specific) question. If none of the answers help, then you need to reform your question (see [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) for hints on this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using C++, and have access to the standard library, this could be written much cleaner as safer as a [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/?kw=vector):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    //Random number from 3 to 7
    int numberOfVectors = (rand() % 7) + 3;

    //Random number from 1 to 10.
    int size = (rand() % 10) + 1;

    std::cout << "There are " << numberOfVectors << " vectors." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Each vector has " << size  << " elements." << std::endl;

    std::vector< std::vector<int> > vectorOfVectorOfInt;

    std::cout << "Value per element: 0 = Not available, 1 = available" << std::endl;

    for(int vec = 0; vec < numberOfVectors; vec++)
    {
        //Create a new vector with 'size' elements.
        std::vector<int> newVector(size);

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            //Generate a random value between 0 and 50
            newVector[i] = (rand() % 50);
        }

        //Add the vector to our vector-of-vectors.
        vectorOfVectorOfInt.push_back(newVector);

        std::cout << "The values for Vector #" << (vec+1) << " is:";
        for(int b = 0; b < size; b++)
        {
            int value = vectorOfVectorOfInt[vec][b];
            std::cout << "\t" << value;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can run it and see the results here: http://ideone.com/RWQhjO

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of array:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main(){
   srand(time(0));
    //random numbers 1 to 10 for Time:
    int t = rand() % 10 + 1 ;
    cout << "Time per F: 0 Not available, 1 available";
    const int f_num = 5;
    cout << "There is "<< t << "Time";
    int* F = new int*[f_num];
    for(int i = 0; i < f_num; i++){
       F[i] = new int[t];
       cout << "The Time for F"<<i<<" is :";
       for(int j = 0; j < t; j++){
          //random numbers 0 or 1:
          F[i][j] = rand() % 2 ;
          cout << " "<< F1[i][j] <<" ";
       }
    }
}
```

BTW, your code is C-like. In C++, we usually use `std::vector` instead of plain array, and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random instead of rand() . Also, don't use `using namespace std` . This can cause name clashes.

Comment: When I do it I have this error
`t' cannot appear in a constant-expression 
For this line: int** F = new int[f_num][t];

Comment: strange. Let me think about it :S

Comment: `int** F = new int[f_num][t];`? Could you not use standard containers instead?

Comment: @Johnsyweb He should use a `std::vector` . However, I don't use it to avoid excessive modifying his code. I am going to post this notice in my answer.

Comment: It might be true I'm new using c++ before I code in C. I don't know about vector so I will take a look

Comment: @user2152947 `std::vector` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector . The syntax might look strange for you. However, you will get used to it soon. One of the advantage of using `std::vector` is that you don't have to care about memory management. In the code above, you should `delete[] F[i]` after using to prevent memory leak.

Comment: @user2152947 You may read the answer provided by Jamin Grey to see how to use `std::vector` . That's a pretty good example.

Answer (score 0):

> I try to use the random function for different things.

Random things, presumably.

> For now it works but I get one problem is I want to generate randomly the F in my code but they need to become array after.

You can generate this just as you generated your value for `t`.

```
const int number_of_fs = rand() % 10 + 1;
std::cout << "Working with " << number_of_fs << " Fs" << std::endl;
```

> Also I need to use it and if I need to do it 1 by 1 I think my code will be too long and messy. Do you know how I can do this?

Your code is already too long and messy and has memory leaks. You should be using containers from the Standard [Containers library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), rather than pointers to pointers that never get `delete`d.

Here is how your code might look were you to use a `std::map` of `std::vector`s for instance:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    srand(time(0));
    //random numbers 1 to 10 for Time:
    const int t = rand() % 10 + 1;
    std::cout << "There is "<< t << " Time" << std::endl;
    const int number_of_fs = rand() % 10 + 1;
    std::cout << "Working with " << number_of_fs << " Fs" << std::endl;

    std::map<int, std::vector<int> > f;

    std::cout << "Time per F: 0 Not available, 1 available" << std::endl;

    for (int f_slot = 1; f_slot <= number_of_fs; ++f_slot) {
        for(int i = 0; i < t; i++){
            //random numbers 0 or 1:
            f[f_slot].push_back(rand() % 2);
        }
        std::cout << "The Time for F" << f_slot << " is " << std::endl;
        std::copy(f[f_slot].begin(), f[f_slot].end(), 
            std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[See it run](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3DapKz%241)!

Population and printing of the contents of these containers should probably be extracted into separate functions, of course, but I didn't want to re-write your code *completely*.